# Code/Function/Library to intent/format/prettify JavaScript/QtScript code for readablity within the application?

Tags: javascript, qt, code-formatting, indentation

Greetings,

in one of my applications I provide a simple code editor based on a `QTextEdit` widget and the `QSyntaxHighlighter`. I was wondering if there is function, library or generally a way to allow the user to have his/her code re-formatted and indented within the application?

Websites like [this](http://www.javascriptbeautifier.com/) allow you to re-format and intent JavaScript/QtScript/ECMAScript code easily, but it would be nice to have a "Format Code" button right next to the code editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to experiment with [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) or [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/). Although these programs are mostly made to format C/C++, they *might* give acceptable results with javascript.